# Variables in Matlab declared inside a nested condition are then accessed outside of the scope

Tags: matlab

This doesn't make sense in any other language I've seen:

```
for...
  if (...)
    if (...)
       ids = [1,2,3;4,5,6]
    end
  end
end

K = ids(:,3)
```

I can't find any reference in the Matlab docs, but that to me in C, Ruby, Javascript, PHP, Java, Python, heck even Ada95, should not work. It's not in the input parameters of the function, it's not declared anywhere else.

This approach is used twice in this code attached to a paper though. Can anyone shed light? Is there just global scope in Matlab?

Comment: I asked the same question in a Mathworks forum and they basically told me it is the programmer's responsibility not to be messy. See the reply [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/79542-variables-created-inside-if-statements). I was disappointed with the answer, but this is Matlab :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable first declared and defined inside a loop is not global, but you can declare a variable just about anywhere.  I don't believe there is scope more local than a function.  In general, scope is very broad in MATLAB.  I'd agree that the scope of a non-`global` variable is limited to the *function* in which it's defined, but there are a couple of unusual ways in which variables can get passed around in MATLAB.

---

One oddity that seems to defy usual scope rules is function handles.  Unlike many other languages where a function handle is little more than a pointer to the function in memory, MATLAB stores a workspace for a function handle.  For example:

```
>> a = pi;
>> aFun = @(r) a*r.^2;
>> a = 1
>> aFun(1/sqrt(2))

ans =

    1.5708
```

The handle swallows up the initial value of `a`:

```
>> finfo = functions(aFun)

finfo = 

     function: '@(r)a*r.^2'
         type: 'anonymous'
         file: ''
    workspace: {[1x1 struct]}

>> finfo.workspace{1}

ans = 

    a: 3.1416
```

---

Function handles to nested functions are also another way to make a variable accessible outside of their original scope, including the nested function itself, which can even be made accessed outside of that file!  Again it does it by storing the value at the time the handle is created.  Consider the function:

```
function [y,hf] = nestTest(x)

    a = 2; b = 1;

    y = nestFun(x);

    hf = @nestFun;

    function y = nestFun(x)
        y = a*x + b;
    end

end
```

It calls the nested function, but also returns a handle to it.  It would seem to not be defining `a` and `b`, but it works:

```
>> [y,hf] = nestTest(2)    
y =

     5

hf = 

    @nestTest/nestFun
```

And so does the handle:

```
>> hf(2)    
ans =

     5
```

Again because it stores an internal workspace with the values that it inherited when it was defined:

```
>> finfo = functions(hf)

finfo = 

     function: 'nestTest/nestFun'
         type: 'nested'
         file: 'C:\Users\Jon.bobs-tavern\Documents\MATLAB\nestTest.m'
    workspace: {[1x1 struct]}

>> finfo.workspace{1}

ans = 

     y: 5
    hf: @nestTest/nestFun
     x: 2
     a: 2
     b: 1
```

See [Preserving Data from the Workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preserving-data-from-the-workspace.html) for more info.  Also, the MATLAB editor has [highlighting to help indicate scope](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-variable-scope-in-editor.html).

---

Another thing to keep in mind, which should be familiar to users of other programming languages, is the stack (or the workspace in which the variable exists).  You can use `assignin` to directly assign a variable to the caller or "base" workspace.

Answer (score 4):

I believe (though if someone wishes to contradict me I'll be interested to learn) that MATLAB variable scope is limited to the *function* it's defined in, not the *block*. So a variable defined within an if-else block within a function is accessible outside that block, but only within the same function. Basically, each function has its own workspace, and variables defined within that function all go into that workspace. It gets a bit more complicated when we start using nested functions and such, and for that I refer you to the very helpful [Art of MATLAB Blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/01/16/nested-functions-and-variable-scope/).

For your second question, MATLAB does has global scope - functions defined as

```
global var
```

are defined within the global workspace, and can be accessed anywhere* in MATLAB. If you define a variable as global within one function, you can access the variable in another function by repeating the `global var` statement. Read [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) for more information.

*Note that global variables don't work well with parallelised code (for instance, within a par-for loop.